# Set an Entity Id as a function of other Entity

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entity, relationship

I use the FOFUserBundle. Whenever a user is registered it creates a new entry in the database. For extension purposes I want another table that saves the Id and Username of that user. Later on I use it for creating slugs and other functionalities.

I implemented a Listener to get confirmation when a user is succesfully registered and then transfer the data to the Author Entity. Just passing the $name fields it does work if @Id generation strategy is set to Auto in the AUhor Entity. But I get the following error with the presented setting:

""Entity of type Vlag\ModelBundle\Entity\Author is missing an assigned ID for field 'author_id'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.""

Here are the involved files:

Listener:

```
namespace Vlag\CoreBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Vlag\ModelBundle\Entity\Author;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use Users\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class MyUserRegistrationListener extends FilterUserResponseEvent implements     EventSubscriberInterface
{
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'addAuthor',
    );
}

public function addAuthor(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();

    $author = new Author();
    $author->setName($user->getUsername());
    $author->setAuthor_Id($user->getId());

    $this->em->persist($author);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

}

User.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(
 *      targetEntity="Author",
 *      mappedBy="author_id")
 */
protected $id;

seters and getters ....
```

Author.php

```
**
 * Author
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vlag\ModelBundle\Repository\AuthorRepository")
 */
class Author extends Timestampable
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="author_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(
 *      targetEntity="User",
 *      inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *      name="author_id",
 *      referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $author_id;
```

How can I solve it? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make a one to one relation between author and user and have author_id be your unique id?  You can only do one or the other.  Give your author entity a regular id then add a user property with a one to one relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a OneToOne on your User's primary key.  It should be a separate $author variable:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Author")
     * @JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $author;
}
```

It's easier to manage if you keep it unidirectional and just access Author through the User entity, but if you want it to be bidirectional you can add this to the Author entity:

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

You are trying to make sure User and Author have the exact same id/primary key, and that's not necessary with a OneToOne relation.  Make sure you have an `author_id` column on your user table and just use that.